# Operation could destabilize runtime, works local, not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my Action:

```
Imports PagedList

<EmployeeAuthorize()>
Function SearchFoods(Optional ByVal date1 As String = "", Optional ByVal keyword As String = "", Optional page As Integer = 1) As ActionResult

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(date1) Then
        date1 = Date.Now
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) Then
        keyword = Nothing
    End If

    Dim food = db.Tbl_Foods.Where(Function(x) x.Shrt_Desc.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Food_ID).ToList

    For Each item In food
        item.Shrt_Desc = item.Shrt_Desc.Replace(",", ", ")
    Next

    ViewBag.MyDate = date1
    ViewBag.MyKeyword = keyword

    ' set the page size and number
    Dim pageSize = 20
    Dim pageNumber = page

    TempData("CurrentPage") = "My Wellness"
    TempData("CurrentWellnessPage") = "Food Log"
    Return View("", "_FinalWellnessSubPageLayout", food.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize))

End Function
```

I believe this is caused, somehow, by the "ToPagedList" since this is the first time I am using it.  It works fine on local, but not when I publish to the server.  The stack trace looks like this:

> [VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
>   PagedList.PagedList`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 superset, Int32 pageNumber,
>   Int32 pageSize) +0
>   PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList(IEnumerable`1 superset,
>   Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize) +62

It also says:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

What is the exception?  How can I find what exception "occurred during the execution?"

Does anyone know how to fix this error on the server?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12560986/25727

Comment: See this: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/issues/35

Comment: @Jan:  Thank you so much.  The first link helped, I just needed to update PagedList.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem with IIS 7.5 it was working fine with IIS 6.0 so I reinstalled the Pagedlist package and it worked like a charm.