# Will VS2012 built .Net 4.0 assembly run in machines where .Net 4.5 is not installed

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, mscorlib

I know the question is a bit strange, but I am asking it because I have faced some issues with it.

I have Visual Studio RTM 2012 installed side by side with VS2010. According to [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750762/problems-building-after-installing-vs-2012-rc) in case of side by side installation of VS2012 and VS2010 some of .Net 4.0 files are replaced with 4.5 version (`mscorlib.dll`,`system.core`).

I tried virtualizing one application built with VS2012 for .Net 4.0 using spoon virtual application studio but it showed  `System.core file not found` error.

I replaced the `mscorlib.dll` and `system.Core` dlls from `Windows\Microsoft.net\4.0` with `<ProgramFiles>\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` files which fixed the file not found error, but this time it showed a `WindowsBase 4.0.0.0/3.0.0.0 file not found` error.

I fear that if I run this application in machines where .Net 4.5 is not installed (WinXP machines) may produce error, but I don't have a separate machine to test it. Can good folks here confirm this?

Comment: You may want to see these previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458159/how-to-keep-net-4-0-behavior-if-net-4-5-is-installed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499351/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-4-5-app-on-xp  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net

Answer (score 1):

Officially, if you target .NET 4.0, it should work just fine on a .NET 4.0 machine, including Windows XP. If this is NOT the case, it is absolutely a bug. I'm not saying there aren't some incompatibilities between 4.0 & 4.5, but if you find something that works on a 4.5 machine, but it doesn't work on a 4.0 machine, we'll view it as a bug.

As far as the 'not having a WinXP machine to test it on', I'd suggest just running a VM. The testing problem is real, and while most people don't have issues, if you don't test, Murphy's Law would likely apply, and your app wouldn't work :-/

-Kev